# Play 2.5 and YourKit

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.5, yourkit

I upgraded a Play serve from 2.4.2 to 2.5 and now whenever I enable YourKit profiler, YourKit and the Play server both slow to a crawl.

Anybody have experience profiling Play 2.5 servers?

I tried configuring both native and jdk sockets but neither helped.

Answer (score 0):

CPU tracing mode is slow on Play 2.5; CPU sampling works fine (still kinda slow though)